# Sporadic access denied error with photos stored on filesystem in ASP.net MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filesystems, photo, access-denied

### Some Background

I have an ASP.net MVC 4 web application which provides access to a large number of photos. Each photo is given a unique ID from a MySQL table which then makes up the filename in hex form and stored in a folder on the file system.

For example:

> D:\Photos\69F.jpg

Throughout the application, different sized thumbnails are displayed which are created using the original photo. Since the thumbnails are changed very rarely, if at all, the thumbnails are created and saved to the same file-system folder in the following formats. (This means that 90% of the time, the photo can simply be returned immediately without any image processing).

- **Thumbnail Normal** - D:\Photos\69F_t.jpg
- **Thumbnail Map** - D:\Photos\69F_tm.jpg

All photos are accessed through a special controller (**ImageController**), this controller has a number of actions depending on the type of thumbnail that is required. For example, if a normal thumbnail is required, the **Thumb** action must be called which then determines whether the thumbnail exists and if not, creates & saves it before returning it to the browser.

> \Image\Thumb\1695

*The application is running under an account which has full access to the folder mentioned above and since most of the time this works, this cannot be a permissions issue!*

### The issue

The problem I have is that I am getting sporadic errors being reported from the application when calls are being made to get thumbnails. The errors all follow the format below, but of course the photo ID changes (i.e., it happens on more than 1 photo):

> The process cannot access the file 'D:\Photos\69F_t.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

or...

> Access to the path 'D:\Photos\69F_t.jpg' is denied.

The errors above are both originating from **Return File(...)** line in the final **Try...Catch**:

```
Function Thumb(Optional ByVal id As Integer = Nothing)

    Dim thumbImage As WebImage
    Dim dimension As Integer = 200

    ' Create the image paths
    Dim imageOriginal As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("imageStore") + Hex(id) + ".jpg"
    Dim imageThumb As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("imageStore") + Hex(id) + "_t.jpg"

    ' If no image is found, return not found
    If FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(imageOriginal) = False Then
        Return New HttpNotFoundResult
    End If

    ' If a thumbnail is present, check its validity and return it
    If FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(imageThumb) = True Then
        thumbImage = New WebImage(imageThumb)

        ' If the dimensions are correct, simply return the image
        If thumbImage.Width = dimension Then
            thumbImage = Nothing
            Return File(imageThumb, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
        End If
    End If

    ' If we get this far, either the thumbnail is not the right size or does not exist!
    thumbImage = New WebImage(imageOriginal)

    ' First we must make the image a square
    If thumbImage.Height > thumbImage.Width Then
        ' Portrait
        Dim intPixelRemove As Integer

        ' Determine the amount to crop off the top and bottom
        intPixelRemove = (thumbImage.Height - thumbImage.Width) / 2
        thumbImage.Crop(intPixelRemove, 0, intPixelRemove, 0)
    Else
        ' Landscape
        Dim intPixelRemove As Integer

        ' Determine the amount to crop off the top and bottom
        intPixelRemove = (thumbImage.Width - thumbImage.Height) / 2
        thumbImage.Crop(0, intPixelRemove, 0, intPixelRemove)
    End If

    thumbImage.Resize(dimension + 2, dimension + 2, True, True)
    thumbImage.Crop(1, 1, 1, 1)
    thumbImage.Save(imageThumb)
    thumbImage = Nothing

    Try
        Return File(imageThumb, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return New HttpNotFoundResult
    End Try

End Function
```

### The questions

I'm pretty sure that something has left the file open so is not letting the application return the file to the browser, but whatever it is, its very sporadic as this works fine on 90-95% of calls.

Either that or the issue is due to concurrency as more than 1 person tries to access the same file.

1. Can anyone spot what might be causing this?
2. Am I likely to suffer more issues if multiple people try to access the same photo thumbnail at the same time?